# How to create a Boolean array in numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, optimization, bigdata

I have to deal with a large data (300 by 4 by 1400000 integer array) which is around

```
4byte * 300 * 4 * 1400000 = 6.72GB
```

However, this array only contains 0 or 1. So if I could use a boolean array, then the size would shrink to 6.25% of the original data.

```
6.72GB / 4bytes / 8bits/bytes * 2 = 420Mbits
```

Is there any way to make use of boolean arrays in numpy?

**EDIT:**
I don't know why he deleted his answer but this did exactly what I wanted.

```
arr = np.ones((300,2,1400000), dtype = np.bool)
```

This lead to 12.5% compression.

```
>>> arr = np.ones((300,2,1400000), dtype = np.bool)
>>> arr.nbytes
840000000

>>> arr = np.ones((300,2,1400000))
>>> arr.nbytes
6720000000

840000000/6720000000 = 12.5%
```

Comment: "this array only contains 0 or 1 ... each element has 2 bits" - uh, what? How does it take 2 bits to represent that?

Answer (score 3):

While there is a way to manipulate 'bit fields' in [numpy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.packbits.html) these don't offer the conveniences of proper numpy arrays on a bit level.

That said, numpy does have "logical" or "boolean" arrays, i.e. arrays with dtype bool. These take only one byte per element and are proper arrays. When your array is created by a "logical array operation" like, say, `b = (a > 0)` it (`b`) will be automatically of bool type. You can obtain boolean arrays by the standard numpy ways a.astype(bool), array(..., dtype=bool) etc.

Comment: Thank you. I use h5py to load arrays from .mat data file. It seems like even though the data only contain 0s and 1s, I get integer arrays. so I will use dtype = np.bool parameter to convert it to a bool array.

Comment: @takataka I think hdf5 uses or is able to use compression which would ameliorate the waste considerably. Not sure though what exactly "matlab-hdf5" does. Anyway, your plan looks good to me.

Answer (score 1):

This will give you a 75% reduction, four bytes per item to one byte per item.

```
bool_array = np.logical_and(int_array, True)
```